# How to pivot Snowflake table in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-pivot, revenue

I am trying to show revenue by products and month as a pivot style table. I have dates ranging back to 2020 but this is something I can filter on when selecting. Each month may have multiple revenue activity so I am looking for the sum of that entire month, ie show me entire revenue for month of April.

This is an example of information in the existing table

| **product** | **date_sold** | **revenue** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| software | 2021-11-13 | $ 1000 |
| hardware | 2022-02-17 | $ 570 |
| labor | 2020-04-30 | $ 472 |
| hardware | 2020-04-15 | $ 2350 |

I'm not very experienced in sql, but I tried google searching and looking over stackoverflow and this is what I'm tinkering with.
`

```
SELECT
    product,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mar,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS May,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dec
FROM
(Select 
product,
revenue,
date_trunc('month', date_sold) as month
  from
    fct_final_net_revenue) source
PIVOT
(   SUM(revenue)
    FOR month
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth;
```

This is what I'd like the results to look like

| product | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | July | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Software | 0 | 1200 | 1200 | 1200 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 150 | 175 | 300 |
| Labor | 0 | 0 | 150 | 2822 | 150 | 150 | 150 | 150 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Hardware | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 75 | 75 | 75 | 75 |

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Thank you @NickW! Just updated for better viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use column names such as `month`; avoiding reserved words / key words, etc, makes code easier to read and avoids errors.

Then, use `MONTH()` to get the month without the year part. Don't truncate to a month, that keeps the year.

The pivot then needs to refer to the values in the column being pivotted. Using `[1]` implies a column name, however; `'1'` is a string and `1` is an integer.

Finally, you can alias the columns from the pivot.

```
SELECT
  pvt_month.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    product,
    revenue,
    MONTH(date_sold)   AS month_sold
  FROM
    fct_final_net_revenue
)
  AS source
PIVOT
(
  SUM(revenue)
    FOR month_sold IN (
      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
    )
)
  AS pvt_month(
    product, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
  )
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html